# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read properties of null (reading 'product')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, react-redux, e-commerce

This error appears to me when I add something to the shopping cart . I've checked the code many times, but I still can't find the solution, I don't know how to make it work.

code in cartActions.js

```
import axios from 'axios' 
import { CART_ADD_ITEM } from '../constants/cartConstants';

export const addToCart = (id, qty) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products/${id}`)

    dispatch({
        type: CART_ADD_ITEM,
        payload: {
            product: data._id, 
            name: data.name,
            image: data.image,
            price: data.price,
            countInStock: data.countInStock, 
            qty
        }


    })

    localStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(getState().cart.cartItems))
}
```

code in cardReducers.js
I think the problem comes from here, but I don't know exactly where to change

```
import {  CART_ADD_ITEM  } from "../constants/cartConstants"

export const cartReducer = (state = { cartItems: [] }, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case CART_ADD_ITEM:
            const item = action.payload
            const existItem = state.cartItems.find(x => x.product === item.product)

            if(existItem){
                return{
                    ...state,
                    cartItems: state.cartItems.map(x =>
                        x.product === existItem.product ? item:x)
                }

            }else{
                return{
                    ...state,
                    cartItems:[...state.cartItems, item]
                }
            }
        
        default:
            return state;

    }



}
```

code in CartScreen.js

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'
import { useParams, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import { Row, Col, ListGroup, Image, Form, Button, Card } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Message } from '../components/Message';
import { addToCart } from '../actions/cartActions';


function CartScreen() {
  const {prodId} = useParams()
  const location = useLocation()
  const qty = location.search ? Number(location.search.split('=')[1]) : 1
  
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const cart = useSelector(state => state.cart)
  const { cartItems } = cart

  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (prodId) {
      dispatch(addToCart (prodId, qty))
    }
      
      
  }, [dispatch, prodId, qty])

  return(
    <div>
      Cart
    </div>
  )

};

export default CartScreen
```

Here I have attached an image with the error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjBhl.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why did you remove the else statement? Of course it won't work if you omit this logic :D

The code inside the store.js seems fine. Please clear your local storage and try again. If you don't know how to do that, delete your browser data or follow the guide [here](https://www.leadshook.com/help/how-to-clear-local-storage-in-google-chrome-browser/).

Answer (score 0):

x is null so you can't access the product property on it. Just use optional chaining here or add an if check.
This should fix the error:

```
const existItem = state.cartItems.find(x => x?.product === item.product)
```

But don't know why the item even is null, maybe you should figure that out first.

Comment: I'm a beginner . What do you mean by '' use optional chaining here or add an if check ''?

Comment: You have to make sure the variable x is not null or undefined before trying
to access the "product" property on it, otherwise it will throw the error you
provided in the title and screenshot. You can do this either by an if check or optional chaining. You can read more about optional chaining [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

Comment: So basically you have 4 options to modify the `find` method:

1. `x => x?.product === item.product`

2. `x => {if (x == null) {return false;} else {return x.product === item.product;}`

3. `x => x == null ? false : x.product === item.product`

4. `x => x != null && x.product === item.product`

Comment: in cartReducers.js at  const existItem = state.cartItems.find(x => {
                if(x == null){
                    return false;
                }else{
                    return x.product === item.product;
                }


            })

Comment: is this where it needs to be changed?

Comment: yes this has to be changed

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

this is the modified code as you told me, but i have the same error. sorry to bother you but i really don t have anyone to ask .thank you very much for your help

cartReducer.js code

```
import {  CART_ADD_ITEM  } from "../constants/cartConstants"


export const cartReducer = (state = { cartItems: [] }, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case CART_ADD_ITEM:
           
            const item = action.payload
            const existItem = state.cartItems.find(x => {
                if(x == null){
                    return false;
                }else{
                    return x.product === item.product;
                }
            })

            if(existItem){
                return{
                    ...state,
                    cartItems: state.cartItems.map(x =>
                        x.product === existItem.product ? item:x)
                }

            }else{
                return{
                    ...state,
                    cartItems:[...state.cartItems, item]
                }
            }
        
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

cartScreen.js code

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'
import { useParams, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import { Row, Col, ListGroup, Image, Form, Button, Card } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Message } from '../components/Message';
import { addToCart } from '../actions/cartActions';


function CartScreen() {
  const {prodId} = useParams()
  const location = useLocation()
  const qty = location.search ? Number(location.search.split('=')[1]) : 1
  
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const cart = useSelector(state => state.cart)
  const  {cartItems}  = cart
  console.log('cartItems:', cartItems)  
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (prodId) {
      dispatch(addToCart (prodId, qty))
    }
      
  }, [dispatch, prodId, qty])

  return(
    <div>
      Cart
    </div>
  )
};

export default CartScreen
```

This appears when I access one of the products and click on the shopping cart to select the quantity

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WedBD.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's the same error just for the `map` method on line 24. So all you have to do is add another if statement to check wether x is null or undefined, just like above.

It should look like this:

```
return {
    ...state,
    cartItems: state.cartItems.map(x => {
      if (x != null) {
        return x.product === existItem.product ? item : x
      } else {
        return x
      }
    })
}
```

or with optional chaining:

```
return{
    ...state,
    cartItems: state.cartItems.map(x => x?.product === existItem.product ? item : x)
}
```

Im still wondering why your first item is null. Could it be that you initialized the store with this value?

Answer (score 0):

i checked in all the files and i really don t realize why the first product is null

I noticed now that any product I put in the shopping cart only recognizes the first one.  from what I understand if I add the product with id 3, ie the third product from the store in the console, the product with id 1 is selected, not with id 3

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chYYO.png)

modified code as you said

code in cartReducers.js

```
import {  CART_ADD_ITEM  } from "../constants/cartConstants"




export const cartReducer = (state = { cartItems: [] }, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case CART_ADD_ITEM:
           
            const item = action.payload
            const existItem = state.cartItems.find(x => {
                if(x == null){
                    return false;
                }else{
                    return x.product === item.product;
                }


            })

            if(existItem){
                return {
                    ...state,
                    cartItems: state.cartItems.map(x => {
                      if (x != null) {
                        return x.product === existItem.product ? item : x
                      } else {
                        return x
                      
                      }
                    })
                }


            }
        
        default:
            return state;

    }



}
```

this is the code from store.js

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'
import { productListReducer, productDetailsReducer } from './reducers/productReducers';
import { cartReducer } from './reducers/cartReducers';

const reducer = combineReducers({
    productList: productListReducer,
    productDetails: productDetailsReducer,
    cart: cartReducer,
})


const cartItemsFromStorage = localStorage.getItem('cartItems') ?
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartItems')) : []


const initialState = {
    cart: { cartItems: cartItemsFromStorage } 
}


const middleware = [thunk]

const store = createStore (reducer, initialState, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware)))

export default store
```